# underscore template issue with json objects

Tags: javascript, regex, backbone.js, underscore.js

Im trying to print a json object using underscore but it is not displaying. If I use the default template for underscore it works but since I am using JSP, I cannot use the default template for underscore. I'm trying to change it so that {{ }} works as my template instead.

I have the following templateSettings :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    _.templateSettings = {

           evaluate: /\{\{#(.+?)\}\}/g,
           interpolate: /\{\{([^#].*?)\}\}/g
      };
  </script>
```

My json file looks like

```
{

"input": {

    "birthday": "Birthday" 
},..
```

}
My template file is:

```
  <script type = "text/template" id ="name">
     Name2: {{ name2 }} // prints  [object Object]<br />
     Name2.input: {{ name2.input }} //doesnt print <br />
     Name2.input.birthday: {{ name2.input.birthday }} //doesnt print
  </script>
```

Is there something wrong with the regex?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your expected vs. actual results?  I put your exmaple into a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7zRf/) and get slightly different results.

Comment: @muistooshort that doesnt cover json objects though

Comment: Sorry, I think I jumped the gun on the "overlapping regexes".

Comment: How are you calling the template? Can you provide a demo? @psquared's demo works as expected for me.